# PHP cURL upload not working

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

I am trying to `POST` a file from URL using PHP cURL to the another server and getting an error:

> There was error in processing your request.

Here is my code:

```php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/api/uploads';
$fields = array('id' => $apikey,'token' => $token ,'myFile' => array(urlencode(base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf")))));
$data_json = json_encode($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 'cache-control: max-age'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Please give the error, it would be helpful to understand...

Comment: Does the server receiving the upload accept POST requests from the remote URL? In other words, [does it have the appropriate CORS settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field should be like this if you want to upload a file.

```
// file from your local directory
$fields = array('id' => $apikey,'token' => $token ,'myFile' => "@/samples/pdf.pdf");
```

And the post fields should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Remove the option `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.